# Undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write' in Amber18 configure

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gfortran, configure

I had problems installing Amber18 on Ubuntu 22. I thought the problem could probably because gcc-11.2 compiler is incompatible with Amber. (I read about the problems of old Amber with gcc-11 on the Amber forum) For this reason I have installed gcc-9, g++-9 and gfortran-9 instead according to the following scheme:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-9
sudo apt-get install g++-9
sudo apt-get install gfortran-9

gfortran --version
gcc -v
g++ -v
```

Than I created a symbolic link from GCC to whichever version of GCC I want.
I can see the symbolic link :

```
ls -la /usr/bin | grep gcc-11.2
ls -la /usr/bin | grep g++-11.2
ls -la /usr/bin | grep gfortran-11.2
```

I removed the GCC symlink and the G++ symlink and then recreate them linked to GCC 9.4 and G++ 9.4:

```
rm /usr/bin/gcc
rm /usr/bin/g++
rm /usr/bin/gfortran

ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-9 /usr/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-9 /usr/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran-9 /usr/bin/gfortran
```

Now if we check the symbolic links again we will see GCC & G++ are now linked to GCC 9.4 and G++ 9.4:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep g++
ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep gfortran
```

Finally we can check our GCC -v again and make sure we are using the correct version:

```
gcc -v
g++ -v
gfortran --version
```

But I have now a problen with gfortran since it fails during configuration test:

```
./configure --with-netcdf $AMBERHOME/netCDF gnu
```

which gives:

```
Warning: without the Python development libraries and headers you
Obtaining the gnu compiler suite versions, e.g.:
     gcc -v

Testing the gcc compiler:
OK

Testing the g++ compiler:
     g++ -fPIC  -o testp testp.cpp
OK


Testing the gfortran compiler:
     gfortran -fPIC  -O0 -o testp testp.f 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqhIZ0h.o: in function `MAIN__':
testp.f:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/usr/bin/ld: testp.f:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/usr/bin/ld: testp.f:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqhIZ0h.o: in function `main':
testp.f:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
/usr/bin/ld: testp.f:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./configure2: 2485: ./testp: not found
Error: Unable to compile a Fortran program using gfortran -fPIC  -O0
       Please check your compiler settings and configure flags.
Configure failed due to the errors above!
```

So, guys, please, I need help with my installation!

P.S. Fortran flags from config.h:

```
FC=gfortran
FFLAGS= -fPIC  $(LOCALFLAGS) $(CUSTOMBUILDFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $(NETCDFINC)  $(AMBERBUILDFLAGS)
FNOOPTFLAGS= -O0
FOPTFLAGS= -O3 -mtune=native
AMBERFFLAGS=$(AMBERBUILDFLAGS)
FREEFORMAT_FLAG= -ffree-form
LM=-lm
FPP=cpp -traditional -P
FPPFLAGS= -DBINTRAJ -DEMIL  $(CUSTOMBUILDFLAGS) $(AMBERBUILDFLAGS)
AMBERFPPFLAGS=$(AMBERBUILDFLAGS)
FCREAL8=-fdefault-real-8
NOFORTRANMAIN=-lgfortran -w
FWARNFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unused-function
```

Comment: Is there any log file?

Comment: Sorry, I did not find any logs.

Comment: I would first reinstall all your gfortran versions. Next, if you want to try a different version of gcc, you just use `./configure CC=gcc-9 CXX=g++-9 FC=gfortran-9`. You do not need to rewrite your symlinks.